# Why can't button display score on the screen?

Tags: java, android, button

I am trying create a simple quiz app where depending from user choices in checkBoxes, submitButton displays the result on the screen. When answer is right score increase 1 point, if answer is wrong score decrease 1 point.
    I am totaly stuck!

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int score;
    Button submitButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitAnswer);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               submitButton.setText(score);
            }
        });
    }

    public void checkBoxes(View view) {

        CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        boolean hasCheckBox1 = checkBox1.isChecked();

        CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        boolean hasCheckBox2 = checkBox2.isChecked();

        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.checkBox1:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Hooray!Your answer is right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               score ++;
                break;
            case R.id.checkBox2:
                Toast.makeText(this,"Sorry, try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                score --;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.allyouask.practicebutton.MainActivity">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RightAnswer"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="179dp"
        android:onClick="checkBoxes"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="WrongAswer"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:onClick="checkBoxes"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitAnswer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your code seems to be ok, bit redundant, but ok, what problem you have? any error? can you post stacktrace?

Comment: So.. what's your exaclty problem?

Comment: The problem is the submit Button of the app, I can't connect how submitButton will show the score of right and wrong answers user have choose

Comment: Guys looking for this 2 days, if anyone can write for me the code, I ll appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to call an *update* method in order to update text on the Button or update its content other way, like this below

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int score;
    Button submitButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitAnswer);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                submitButton.setText(String.valueOf(score));
            }
        });
    }

    public void checkBoxes(View view) {

        CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        boolean hasCheckBox1 = checkBox1.isChecked();

        CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        boolean hasCheckBox2 = checkBox2.isChecked();

        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.checkBox1:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Hooray!Your answer is right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               score ++;
                break;
            case R.id.checkBox2:
                Toast.makeText(this,"Sorry, try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                score --;
                break;
        }
        //submitButton.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to define `score` two times

Comment: Hi ddb,your code works in a way but not exactly what I need,what happen with your code is when the user checks a checkBox automatically the score pops up on the screen. Could you tell me how can it be only when user press submitButton display the score?

Comment: @ElenJ, currently with your code what happens if you click on the submit button? so I'll edit my answer to fix

Comment: @ElenJ, anyway I made a fix in my answer, I think now it should work. (1) I commented the appearing of the submit button when user made a click on a checkbox and (2) I updated the function inside the `OnClickListener` on the submitButton

Comment: What happens now is: when user checks a checkBox the score immediately appears on the button. If you press the submitButton app crashes

Comment: it works!Thanks a lot ddp! your help was very important to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your score in `int` type, you use [setText(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) in this case. So you're trying to load resource with `id==score`.

Try to modify arguments, to use this [version](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) of the `setText` method:

```
submitButton.setText(String.valueOf(score))
```

Comment: Use `String.valueOf(score)`.

Answer (score -1):

you should use:

```
private int score=0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score -1):

try this --> Replace **int score;** line your code with **int score = 0;** and check if it works.

Comment: Int is initialised as 0 by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer